# Unable to make connection to apache derby server

Tags: java, android, derby

I am having a  Apache Derby Network Server - 10.10.2.0 - (1582446) started and ready to accept connections on port 1527.

Now on my Android app side. I am doing some thing like this :

```
 private class SendHttpRequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String startDate = params[1];
        Log.e("START DATE :", "Start date " + startDate);
        try {
            Log.e("URL IS ",params[0]);
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                    .appendQueryParameter("startDate", startDate);
            String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();
            Log.e("BEFORE WRITE","its fine");
            try {
                OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));

                writer.write(query);
                Log.e("AFTER WRITE", "not fine");
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                os.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                Log.e("SILENT ERROR",e.toString());
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("GETTING ERROR ",e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And URL I am using is : http://192.168.1.254:8080/GrabHouseServer/GetVisitTimeSlot.

I looked with 172.0.0.1:8080 also but am not able to establish connection.
192.168.1.254 is the wifi address i got by my airport utility in mac.

But am getting this in logger :

```
SILENT ERROR﹕ java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.1.254 (port 8080): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
GETTING ERROR﹕ java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.1.254 (port 8080): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
```

Am i missing something ? Please help.

Also permission I had given in manifest. So thats not any issue.

Answer (score 0):

An Apache Derby Network Server doesn't speak HTTP protocol; it speaks JDBC protocol.

So you can't open a connection to an Apache Derby Network Server using an URL which is "http:" scheme.

You can openConnection an "http:" URL to a web server.

And then you could have some code in that web server (e.g., a Java servlet), which processed your HTTP GET request and then connected via JDBC to your Derby Network Server, and retrieved some data, and then sent the data back as an HTTP response.

But you have to build that middleware yourself; the Derby Network Server is only a database server, not a web server.